# EntityFramework 6 Code First in Oracle 12.2.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, odp.net

I use entity framework code firts 6.0

I used Oracle Client 12.1.0 and I added that section to  my web.config and it is working

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</providers>
```

I upgrade my drive to oracle 12.2.0 and I change my web.config like this(only Version=6.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" /> part was changed) but I got that error,what I am missing??

> Unhandled Error Occured:System.NotSupportedException: Unable to
>   determine the provider name for provider factory of type
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory'. Make sure that the
>   ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.

```
   <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</providers>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I added this section and it works


<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <!-- Remove in case this is already defined in machine.config -->
  <remove invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
  <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  <add name="EF Tracing Data Provider" invariant="EFTracingProvider" description="Tracing Provider Wrapper" type="EFTracingProvider.EFTracingProviderFactory, EFTracingProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=def642f226e0e59b" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```